# Embed the Autodesk Viewer in a web page

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

In our web application, we want to view AutoCAD files using Autodesk viewer API.
As per our requirement we want to select the file and need to open directly in auto-desk viewer site, where all default options like 2D, 3D views are available.
Is it possible to view those files, directly in Autodesk viewer, instead of creating our own viewer?

Answer (score 3):

We do have a minified online viewer that takes a svf - pls make sure all svf assets are available at the same location and open to public access with CORs allowed:
https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/viewer3d.html?svf=url/to/your/svf (make sure to put in the url to your svf)

But this is NOT an official setup of any sort and is subject to change w/o notice. You are very much encouraged to develop your own, just a few lines of code would do this trick if you already have your models extracted.

Here's a few good places to start:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/basic-viewer/
- http://learnforge.autodesk.io

Tools:

- http://models.autodesk.io
- https://extract.autodesk.io/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Provided links are very useful, however as per our requirement we do not want to create our own viewer using Autodesk API. 
We need to select file from our website, and need to redirect on Autodesk viewer where all default options of Autodesk viewer are available. 
Is it possible to view the file directly in auto-desk viewer site through our web app?

Comment: Unfortunately that would be only viable through embedding the viewer site in an iframe on your site - Forge is by design a set of API and services for developers to build their own apps and not exactly an end product.